# VBA TextBox fill values in colunm to specific range

Tags: excel, vba

My workbook has two sheets: one "Data" and one "Kiert". I solved to copy rows by specific attributes from "data" to "Kiert" with UserForm, but I added ti user form four textboxes (TextBox1, TextBox2 etc.) and I want to fill the database with constant values added in textbox with one command button in blank colums after pasted data.
I have additional textbox5, which indicates if the copy was succefull ("SIKERES"), this part works fine...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Drng As Range, c As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim srcRange As Range, fillRange As Range
    Set a = TextBox5
    Set d = TextBox1
    Set ws = Sheets("Data")
    Set Drng = ws.Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
    For Each c In Drng.Cells
        If c = ListBox1 Then
            c.EntireRow.Copy 
            Sheets("Kiert").Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Range("F:F" & lastRow).Formula = TextBox1.Value
        If c.Value = ListBox1.Value Then
            a.Value = "SIKERES"
        End If
        End If
    Next c 
End Sub
```

I insert here an example:

[image]

My main problem is I cannot describe a correct range and description of textboxes, and I don't know where I can put it in my code to run it properly.

I tried this:

```
    For Each c In Drng.Cells
    If c = ListBox1 Then
        c.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Summary").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Sheets("Kiert").Range("A:A" & lasrRow).Value = TextBox1.Text
        If c.Value = ListBox1.Value Then
            A.Value = "SIKERES"
        End If
    End If
Next c
```

...but its out of range.

Comment: Ermm ok, so what is your question? Do you get an error?

Comment: Hi, i modified my question, and added a photo below, to explain what is my problem.

Comment: Where do you get the value for LastRow?

Comment: My last row is the last filled column in sheet ("Kiert")---this is my output sheet. In data sheet i have a plenty of attributes (circa 500), 10-20 names by attribute. in user form i pick the attribute from listbox, and with Command button i copy this attribute with 10-20 names. Usualy i pick 4-5 attributes per one turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what you are trying to do, but the code below will help you paste the values of your textboxes to the relevant column:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Drng As Range, c As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim NextFreeRow As Long
    Dim srcRange As Range, fillRange As Range
    Set Drng = Sheets("Data").Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
    For Each c In Drng.Cells 'loop through Column A on Sheet Data
        If c = ListBox1.Value Then 'If the cells in Column A Sheet Data matches the selection on your Listbox1 then
            NextFreeRow = Sheets("Kiert").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Check the next free row on Sheet Kiert
            c.EntireRow.Copy Desination:=Sheets("Kiert").Range("A" & NextFreeRow) 'Paste the entire row from Sheet Data to Sheet Kiert
            Range("F" & NextFreeRow).Value = TextBox1.Text 'Copy the contents of TextBox1 to column F
            'Add more lines like the one above to copy the values from your Textboxes to the relevant column
            TextBox5.Text = "SIKERES"
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: yes thank you! :) this is the code what i seached for! the desination=destination was the only one which i needed to correct. i was suffering with this code for days, but you had a very clever sollution

Comment: No problem,... Can you please mark my response as an Answer, if it has helped you? Thank you.